# OperationalError at /admin/sybase_app/packageweight/ (b"Table 'sybase_app_packageweight' not found", -141)

Tags: django, sybase, sqlanydb

When I edit my `admin.py` file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Packageweight

admin.site.register(Packageweight)
```

and the run `python manage.py runserver` and click in the admin page on `Packageweight` it throws this error

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sybase_app/packageweight/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'sybase_app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1548.                 self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in __init__
  82.         self.get_results(request)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in get_results
  177.         result_count = paginator.count
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in _get_count
  72.                 self._count = self.object_list.count()
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in count
  318.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_count
  464.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_aggregation
  445.         result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  829.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  658.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlany_django/base.py" in execute
  98.             ret = self.cursor.execute(trace(query), trace(args))
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlanydb.py" in execute
  796.         self.executemany(operation, [parameters])
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlanydb.py" in executemany
  767.             bind_count = self.api.sqlany_num_params(self.stmt)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlanydb.py" in __stmt_get
  701.             self.handleerror(*self.parent.error())
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlanydb.py" in handleerror
  695.             eh(self.parent, self, errorclass, errorvalue, sqlcode)
File "/home/pd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlanydb.py" in standardErrorHandler
  379.         raise errorclass(errorvalue,sqlcode)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/sybase_app/packageweight/
Exception Value: (b"Table 'sybase_app_packageweight' not found", -141)
```

How could I fix it?

`Ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: I solved it with `db_table` [attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/), but if you have some explanation, or how to avoid that the generated models with `python manage.py inspect db` should be adjusted and every should have `db_table` attribute, I would appreciate it. In that database there are hundreds of tables.

Comment: What did you pass in `db_table` attribute?

Comment: to `class Meta:`

Comment: I mean what is the value?

Comment: `Packageweight` works, but we started rather using the copy of a table `PackageweightTest`. It didn't work before because django was using some prefix of the table for the generated model.

Comment: That's by convention. I still don't know what's the expected result here.

Comment: I will generate more models with `python manage.py inspect db` from the database later. So, I have to create `db_table` attribute for each model? Isn't there some settings for it?

Comment: What do you want to set it to?

Comment: The table name shouldn't be `sybase_app_packageweight`, but only `packageweight`

Comment: `python manage.py inspectdb` already sets `db_table` based on the table name in the database. What's your workflow?